# Java 3d mapping

Tags: java, dictionary, 3d

I'm creating a 3D game based on the book [Developing Games in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592730051) (you don't need to read or know the book to answer). To create the map I'm using a .map file that specifies the walls, floors, ceilings, and so forth. I just don't understand how the walls are created. Instead of using a begin x (coordinate) and a final x, a begin z (coordinate) and a final z, he just uses one x coordinate and one z coordinate. The commands are:

```
#    v [x] [y] [z]        - Define a vertex with floating-point 
#                           coords (x,y,z).
#    mtllib [filename]    - Load materials from an external .mtl 
#                           file.
#    usemtl [name]        - Use the named material (loaded from a 
#                           .mtl file) for the next floor, ceiling,
#                           or wall.
#    ambientLightIntensity 
#        [value]          - Defines the ambient light intensity
#                           for the next room, from 0 to 1.
#    pointlight [v]       - Defines a point light located at the  
#        [intensity]        specfied vector. Optionally, light
#        [falloff]          intesity and falloff distance can
#                           be specified.
#    player [v] [angle]   - Specifies the starting location of the
#                           player and optionally a starting 
#                           angle, in radians, around the y-axis.
#    obj [uniqueName]     - Defines an object from an external
#        [filename] [v]     OBJ file. The unique name allows this
#        [angle]            object to be uniquely identfied, but
#                           can be "null" if no unique name is 
#                           needed. The filename is an external
#                           OBJ file. Optionally, the starting 
#                           angle, in radians, around the y-axis 
#                           can be specified.
#    room [name]          - Defines a new room, optionally giving
#                           the room a name. A room consists of
#                           vertical walls, a horizontal floor
#                           and a horizontal ceiling. Concave rooms
#                           are currently not supported, but can be
#                           simulated by adjacent convex rooms.
#    floor [height]       - Defines the height of the floor of 
#                           the current room, using the current
#                           material. The current material can
#                           be null, in which case no floor 
#                           polygon is created. The floor can be
#                           above the ceiling, in which case a 
#                           "pillar" or "block" structure is 
#                           created, rather than a "room".
#    ceil [height]        - Defines the height of the ceiling of 
#                           the current room, using the current
#                           material. The current material can
#                           be null, in which case no ceiling
#                           polygon is created. The ceiling can be
#                           below the floor, in which case a 
#                           "pillar" or "block" structure is 
#                           created, rather than a "room".
#    wall [x] [z]         - Defines a wall vertex in a room using
#         [bottom] [top]    the specified x and z coordinates.
#                           Walls should be defined in clockwise 
#                           order. If "bottom" and "top" is not
#                           defined, the floor and ceiling height
#                           are used. If the current material is
#                           null, or bottom is equal to top, no
#                           wall polygon is created.
```

Maybe you can understand the "wall instructions" and explain in more details? I'm about 2 days testing some "theories" but I still can't understand. Other thing I don't get: what is the 'v' command for?

PS: Is there a way to create the .map file from a external program (like a program that construct this kind of .map file)? And what would be a vertex?

**Many thanks**

Comment: It would seem that the z is defining the width of the wall

Comment: First, thanks for commenting.

The z is setting the z vector's distortion, you are right. But how can I set the x and z **coordinates**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `wall` command does is define a wall *vertex*. That means that it defines a corner or an endpoint of a wall. You'd need to give multiple wall vertices to define a wall. For instance:

```
wall 0 0
wall 0 2
wall 2 2
```

That will define a wall consisting of two straight pieces in a 90 degree corner.

The height of the wall is defined by the last two optional parameters. I'm not certain how you would go about creating separate pieces of wall though, but perhaps you could find an example of a maze that does this.

Comment: If you would do a simple maze, what code would you use?

Comment: So it works like a polygon?
PS: If you write `wall 100 0 0 0` no wall will appear, creating separate pieces.

Comment: You need multiple `wall` commands to define a piece of wall (if my guess is correct, that is). With each command you specify a corner or endpoint, so yes, just `wall 100 0 0 0` will not create a wall, because it's just 1 endpoint (and moreover it has height 0).

Comment: The `v` command specifies a 3D vertex. It looks like this format is based on the Wavefront .obj files, so I'm guessing you can then reference these vertices with other commands like `pointlight` or `player` by their index (starting at 1 for the first vertex in the file).